# It is requested for the producers

Tags: grammar

*It is requested for the producers this information to be stated on the packing.*

*It is requested so that the producers state this information on the packing.*

I would like to ask whether these two sentences are grammatically OK. I am not sure whether the preposition "for" is needed in the first one.

Comment: #1 ungrammatical.  #2 meaning unclear    What are you trying to say?Are you making a request or describing a request? Are you asking that specifically the manufacturer state something on the packaging? Are you asking only that something be stated on the packaging? Are you giving the rationale for a previous request?

Comment: I want to tell that legislation requests so that the producers of a product give product information on the packing.

Comment: Is it a request or a mandate?  Does the legislation mandate that product information be placed on the packaging?  Are you writing the law or describing the law? Not sure what you meant by **tell**.

Comment: As @Tᴚoɯɐuo says, the first version is completely ungrammatical. The minimum change necessary to "fix" the second version is simply to remove unwanted ***so***, giving the perfectly acceptable *It is requested **that** the producers state this information on the packing*.

Comment: Also note that Google Books has 4580 instances of [*the information on the **packaging***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+information+on+the+packaging%22), but just 7 instances of [*the information on the **packing**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+information+on+the+packing%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mandate:

> Product information must be placed legibly on the packaging.
>
> Legible product information must appear on the packaging.

Description:

> The provision requires manufacturers|producers to place legible product information on the packaging.
>
> It is mandated that producers place legible product information on the packaging.

P.S. If the question is about the verb **request**:

The complement of the verb **request** can be a finite *that*-clause (a noun-clause complement).  The verb can also have an adjunct prepositional phrase indicating who the request is made of.

> It is requested **that** patrons remain quiet in the library.
>
> It is requested **of** patrons that they remain quiet in the library.
>
> We request that you remain quiet.
>
> We request of you that you remain quiet.

There is also the possibility of having a direct object (recast as passive subject) complemented by an infinitive clause:

> We request patrons to remain quiet.
>
> Patrons are requested to remain quiet in the library.

That last pattern can be used with **mandate**:

> Producers are mandated to place product information on the packaging.

But with **mandate** we do not have the prepositional adjunct identifying the mandatee, or I should say we have not had this option historically, though  it seems that **mandated of** is gaining some traction:

> It is mandated of producers that they place ... <sup>UNGRAMMATICAL OR MARGINAL</sup>
>
> It is required of producers that they place ... <sup>OK</sup>
>
> It is ordered of producers that they place ... <sup>UNGRAMMATICAL OR MARGINAL</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you tell me what was wrong with the first sentence? (It is requested for the producers this information to be stated on the packing.)

Comment: You haven't told me whether you are trying to describe the law or to author the law. Nor have you answered my question about whether it is a request or a mandate.

Comment: I am describing the current practice.

Comment: Is it a mandated practice or is the producer given a choice?

Comment: The producers do not have a choice. Absent information on the packing = penalty.

Comment: So, **it is *requested*** while not ungrammatical is inaccurate. It is mandated that product information appear on the packaging.  It is mandated that producers place product information on the packaging.  It is mandated that product information be placed by producers on the packaging.

Answer (score 0):

Samples: It is requested for the producers this information to be stated on the packing. It is requested so that the producers state this information on the packing.

**Minimum change** required to make the sentence grammatical:

1) **It is requested [that] the producers place this information on the packing**.

**request cannot be followed by for or so without introducing a direct object**.

- I requested this so you could finish early.
- I requested this for you, not for me.

ask, demand, determine, insist, move, order, pray, prefer, recommend, regret, request, require, suggest, and wish, follow this pattern. Please note: not all may be used impersonally: it is + past participle. Nevertheless, all take the base form  for the second verb (that is, no **s** in the third person i.e. "subjunctive"). **The to-infinitive is not used with these verbs**. (Often, some these verbs can take a noun or a gerund as well.

The verb request can be followed by a subject + verb or a noun:
- We request **he leave**. [not to finish, not leave**s**]
- They requested **we finish quickly**. 
- She requests **you be on time tomorrow**.
- I requested **a sales' person** be sent to the store.

- to request someone do something

  like the verbs above, use the personal pronoun followed by the base form of the verb: I suggest you leave. They suggest he finish. We suggest  you be on time.

2) Normally, **a simple passive voice** would be less awkward here:

**Passive Voice**: **The manufacturers are requested to place this information on the packaging.**

**Active Voice:** We requested the manufacturers place the information on the  packaging.

3) Generally speaking, we try to avoid an impersonal  in English unless really necessary. So, you might get: "It is advisable that he leave now." or "It is preferable they start now.". However, "It is requested" is pretty awkward in the context of the sample sentence. **I would advise not using it.**

Please note: products are **generally** manufactured, not produced. Films are produced. And **packing** is the paper or other material inside a box or container, and does not usually contain writing. Generally, information is not found on packing (styrofoam, plastic, paper, etc.), it is found  on the package, box or **packaging**.

4) Based on this: I want to tell that legislation requests so that the producers of a product give product information on the packing.

**We would say**:

**The law requires product manufacturers place the information on the  packaging**.

Requires here functions like request.